# @Component-annotation Spring

Tags: java, spring, компоненты

Для каких именно классов используется аннотация @Component?

Есть некоторые проекты, где, вроде-бы, данная аннотация должна использоваться, а она наоборот отсутствует. И это вводит в заблуждение.

Comment: ну так посмотрите используется ли в этом проекте аннотации `Service` или `Repository`

Comment: Точнее :) В каких проектах и почему должна использоваться?
@Component это общий стереотип. В коде принято использовать смысловые аннотации: Controller, Service, Repository - они все компонент.

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ нажав на галочку если он решает вашу проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Component - это общий стереотип для любого компонента Spring.

@Repository, @Service и @Controller являются теми же @Component но для более конкретных случаев использования. Например @Repository, если этот компонент выполняет функции хранилища. Кроме того эти аннотации помогают при работе с исключениями, в случае возбуждения специфического платформенного исключения, ошибка будет перехвачена и затем ретранслирована. Например для случая с @Repository соответственно будет data access exception.

Вы можете аннотировать классы компонентов с помощью @Component,
но, заменив их на аннотации @Repository, @Service или @Controller, ваши классы лучше подойдут для обработки с помощью других полезных инструментов или связи с аспектами (для указания более конкретной цели).

Comment: Я имел ввиду, при использовании данных аннотаций, классы регистрируются в контексте. Вот какие именно классы стоит заносить в контекст для autowiring, а какие нет?)

Comment: @AlekseyDobroshtan ну так помечайте те классы, которые Вы хотите использовать как спринговые бины